# call javascript from server side on link button telerik

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am new to telerik and javascript. I have a link button. On button click I have two conditions from server side. according to that I need to call javascript.

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TestLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="Test_Click" 
SkinID="SmallCommandItemTemplateLinkButton">Test</asp:LinkButton>
```

Server Side Code:

```
protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptsKey", "<script type=\"text/JavaScript\" language=\"javascript\">ShowAlert();</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        TestLinkButton.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("return ShowEditForm('{0}')", test);
    }
}
```

Here it is not able to find TestLinkButton. If I am using GridItemEventArgs in button click arguments, Then it is giving error as No Overload for'testLinkButton_click' matches delegate'System.Eventhandler'.

Comment: I am not familiar with telerik, but I think this has to so with Event delegation. https://www.google.nl/amp/s/davidwalsh.name . Read that, you might find the solution!

Comment: can you share some ideas

Comment: I put a bounty on it, so people with more experience than me can answer this. Like I said, Iam not familiar with Telerik.

Comment: This has nothing to do with telerik.

Comment: @DIPALISAVALIYA - Does one or several answers help you in any way? If so, you can upvote the answers that you like and accept the one that you prefer (with the check mark). I see from your profile that you are relatively new to StackOverflow and haven't got into the habit of upvoting/accepting answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The LinkButton can be retrieved from the `sender` argument of the `Test_Click` event handler, and the Javascript code can be attached to its `OnClientClick` property:

```
LinkButton lnkButton = sender as LinkButton;
lnkButton.OnClientClick = String.Format("return ShowEditForm('{0}')", test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think you are looking for a way to attach the javascript `onclick` to the `LinkButton` in a GridView. You seem to be doing it on a server `OnClick` of the LinkButton, but that will take a roundtrip to the server (PostBack).

You can do the same in the `OnItemDataBound` event of the GridView. You need to add the `OnItemDataBound` to the GridView.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" >
```

Code behind

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the item is a GridDataItem
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        //if 'a' needs to come from the dataset that is bound to the gridview, you can do this
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        string a = Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"].Text);

        //or another grid value
        string b = item["name"].Text;

        //find the linkbutton with findcontrol and cast it back to one
        LinkButton linkbutton= e.Item.FindControl("TestLinkButton") as LinkButton;

        if (a == 0)
        {
            //attach the OnClientClick click function
            linkbutton.OnClientClick = string.Format("ShowDeleteForm('{0}'); return false;", test2);
        }
        else
        {
            //attach the OnClientClick click function
            linkbutton.OnClientClick = string.Format("ShowEditForm('{0}'); return false;", test);
        }
    }
}
```